# Decrypt SQL Data using Software Credentials

Tags: sql, encryption

I have customer trying to swap over to a new application and I found all the relevant tables/columns in SQL for the old application data but a couple of the columns are encrypted.

I have credentials (username/password) that will unencrypt the data from within the old application but it would take way too long to manually go through each record within the software and copy the data to a table.

Is it possible to create a SQL query or procedure that could use those same credentials from within management studio and output the entire dataset unencrypted?  If that's not possible, could there be any other way to unencrypt this data without involving the developer (who is obviously not cooperating since the customer is leaving them).

I tried poking around the Security node of the database in SSMS but there were no Keys, certificates, or anything listed there so I'm not sure exactly how SQL is encrypting the data.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?